# javascript / php - Get src of image from the URL of the site

Tags: javascript, php

I noticed that at [http://avengersalliance.wikia.com/wiki/File:Effect_Icon_186.png](http://avengersalliance.wikia.com/wiki/File%3aEffect_Icon_186.png), there is an image (a small one) there. Click on it, you will be brought to another page: http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140312005948/avengersalliance/images/f/f1/Effect_Icon_186.png.

For [http://avengersalliance.wikia.com/wiki/File:Effect_Icon_187.png](http://avengersalliance.wikia.com/wiki/File%3aEffect_Icon_187.png), after clicking on the image there, you are brought to another page: http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140313020718/avengersalliance/images/0/0c/Effect_Icon_187.png

There are many similar sites, from [http://avengersalliance.wikia.com/wiki/File:Effect_Icon_001.png](http://avengersalliance.wikia.com/wiki/File%3aEffect_Icon_001.png), to [http://avengersalliance.wikia.com/wiki/File:Effect_Icon_190.png](http://avengersalliance.wikia.com/wiki/File%3aEffect_Icon_190.png) (the last one).

I'm not sure if the image link is somewhat related to the link of its parent site, but may I know, is it possible to get `http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140312005948/avengersalliance/images/f/f1/Effect_Icon_186.png` string, from the string `http://avengersalliance.wikia.com/wiki/File:Effect_Icon_186.png`, using PHP or JavaScript? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: The image source is inside the HTML markup of the page. You can extract it with any HTML parser.

Comment: The page source is complicated, how do I extract it?

Comment: By learning about HTML parsers, doing some personal reasearch and finally writing down those 6 lines of PHP... Show some signs of effort, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small PHP script that can do this. It uses CURL to get content and DOMDocument to parse HTML.

```
<?php

    /*
     *  For educational purposes only
     */

    function get_wiki_image($url = '') {

        if(empty($url)) return;

        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $output = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        $DOM = new DOMDocument;

        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $DOM->loadHTML($output);
        libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

        return $DOM->getElementById('file')->firstChild->firstChild->getAttribute('src');
    }

    echo get_wiki_image('http://avengersalliance.wikia.com/wiki/File%3aEffect_Icon_186.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access for example by class and then select the one than you want with [n], after that getAttribute and you got it

```
document.getElementsByClassName('icon cup')[0].getAttribute('src')
```

Hope it helps